# How to change shadow root close to open, React

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am developing a React application. I want to use an SVG file that I imported from illustrator. For that I use [SVGR](https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/svgr/) which allows me to generate a React component from the illustrator code.

I get this component:

```
import React from 'react';

const SvgComponent = props => {
    return (
        <div className="SvgComponent">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 640 480" {...props}>
                <defs>
                    <div>
                    <path
                        id="prefix__a"
                        d="M266.5 87.5c163.9-9.4 296.9 60.1 331 163 22.3 67.2 7.4 164-42 189-50.7 25.7-97.3-44.7-207-30-50.8 6.8-65.7 25.2-103 15-44.6-12.2-90.7-56.9-91-103-.3-51.1 55.8-63.7 55-122-.5-38-24.7-55.3-14-79 10.3-22.7 43.2-30.3 71-33z"
                    />
                    </div>

                </defs>
                <clipPath id="prefix__b">
                    <use xlinkHref="#prefix__a" overflow="visible" />
                </clipPath>
            </svg>
        </div>
    )};

export default SvgComponent
```

The problem is that nothing is displayed, I saw that there was the Shadow Root closed. I'm not familiar with shadow root.
How can I open it?

[image]

I have tried to use [react-shadow-root](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-shadow-root) but it doesn't works.